# MeteorJS: resubscribe/refresh a Collection?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor

I'm currently working on my meteor project and I'm not quite understanding what the Meteor way for my problem is.

I have a subscription which is initially called on pageload. I subscribe the following publication without any parameters:

```
Meteor.publish('testCollection', function(searchitem){
    if(searchitem){
        return testCollection.find({name:searchitem});
    }
    else{
        return testCollection.find({},{
            sort: { rating: -1 },
            limit: 5,
            fields: {
                _id:1,
                name:1,
                description:1
            }
        });
    }
});
```

This works quite well and I get my results from the else-case.
But I want the user to be able to search in this collection for a name.
So my idea of refreshing is to use when submitting searchbutton:

```
Meteor.subscribe("testCollection","abc");
```

But this is not refreshing my clientside testCollection.
How can I achieve this? Do I have to unsubcribe and subscribe again, if yes: how?

Comment: Sanitize your database input! The user could pass a Mongo selector as `searchItem`, use `check(searchItem, Match.OneOf(String, undefined))`.

Comment: Could you please explain this to me? Where should I pass this Mongo selector in my code and where do I call the check-function?

Comment: The check-function is for the publication to proof the variable is only a String or undefined, right?

Comment: Yep. That way you are sure that what the client is sending is what you are expecting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key here is to limit the data sent (and possibly stored) at the client, by always limiting the result.

In short it's all about re-subscribing to the publication. This can be done in a number of ways, but the simplest (and in my oppinion most elegant) is to use autorun with an reactive source such as [Session](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/session) or [ReactiveVar](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/reactive-var). Whenever this source is changed, a new subscribe is triggered and the previous is canceled.

From Meteor docs:
http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_subscribe

> If you call Meteor.subscribe within a reactive computation, for
>   example using Tracker.autorun, the subscription will automatically be
>   cancelled when the computation is invalidated or stopped; it's not
>   necessary to call stop on subscriptions made from inside autorun.

Your code for re-subscribing could look something like this:

```
Tracker.autorun(function() {  
  if (Session.get('someCustomQuery'))
    Meteor.subscribe('testCollection', Session.get('someCustomQuery'));
});
```

I'll recommend this tutorial by David Burles:

http://meteorcapture.com/simple-search-pattern/

Example-code with ReactiveVar, triggered by event:

```
Template.myTemplate.rendered = function(){
  var self = this;

  Tracker.autorun(function() {
    if (self.searchQuery.get())
    {
      var queryOptions = {
        query: self.searchQuery.get()
      };

      Meteor.subscribe('testCollection', queryOptions);
    }
  });
}

Template.myTemplate.created = function(){
  this.searchQuery = new ReactiveVar('');
};

Template.myTemplate.events({
  'keyup [type=search]': function(event, template) {
    template.searchQuery.set(event.target.value);
  }
});
```

Comment: @smoksnes thanks for your answer, I tried it and it worked instantly. So I have to use the Tracker.autorun() with the session? Why can I not simply call Meteor.subscribe('testCollection',searchitem) where I want (maybe in an eventhandler or sth.)?

Comment: @ant45de -> You should be able to call subscribe directly, even though I haven't tried. The power of Meteor is that it's reactive, so you can simplify your code by listening to reactive components no matter where they are used. I added an example with ReactiveVar instead of Session, if you're like me and dislike using Session when it's only used in one template.

Comment: @ant45de You should refer to the documentation for this, it is about reactivity. smoksnes, for your Tracker you may want to check http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_autorun . Also do you know you can simply [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) the function instead of writing `that = this`?

Comment: Come to think of it, you might want to [`_.debounce`](http://underscorejs.org/#debounce) the event handler so that it is not triggered by every single character the user types.

Comment: The reactiveVar solution is also about having a Tracker, it's not making it "easier" than using the session variable. I just wanted to call the Meteor.subscribe() in a simple eventhandler without this "overhead" and I don't understand why this is not possible, what is the reason for this?

Comment: @ant45de The overhead is what makes it possible. What you want to do is create a subscription to get data for a specific search, then if that search changes then change the data. The only way to do this is to cancel the previous subscription and create a new one, which Tracker does pretty damn well.